# how to pass get parameters in named routes in laravel

Tags: laravel

In my `index.blade.php` the code is as follows:

```
href="/finance/reports?type=monthly&year={{ $month['year'] }}&month={{ $month['id'] }}"
```

and in `web.php` file route is defined as:

```
Route::get('/reports', 'ReportsController@index')->name('reports');
```

How can I pass the parameters in index.blade.php to make it a named route.

Answer (score 8):

It is a named route already. To get a URL from the route helper for the named route with the query params appended:

```
route('reports', [
    'type' => 'monthly',
    'year' => $month['year'],
    'month' => $month['id'],
]);
```

Would be:

```
http://yoursite/finance/reports?type=monthly&year=WhatEverThatIs&month=WhatEverThatWas
```

*I'm making assumptions about your routes and that the URI you used in the example is accurate.*

Answer (score 2):

Define the route as:

```
Route::get('/finance/reports/{type}/{year}/{month}')->name('reports');
```

and then use it from blade template the following way:

```
href="{{route('reports', ['type' => 'monthly', 'year' => $month['year'], 'month' => $month['id']])}}"
```

See the docs for more info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#required-parameters

Comment: it is giving me the page you are looking for could not be found.what should I do?

Comment: What is the URL that gets generated in Blade template?

Comment: You missed something @jedrzej.kurylo He needs to pass it as query parameter not path so you should remove the other paths after reports then it should be ok.

Comment: I reverted the changes I made initially to the path just in case I missed the intention of the question

Comment: yeah, thanks @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Define the route as:

Route::get('/reports/{type}/{year}/{month}', 'ReportsController@index');

and use it in following way from the blade template

href="your_project_path/reports/monthly/{{ $month['year'] }}/{{ $month['id'] }}"

Comment: But actually I want to make it a named route